# Make continuous colorbar legend in React with D3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-d3

Good day!

I am very new to working with D3 in React. I want to make a very simple continuous colorbar legend in my React app, that basically looks like this:

[image: Colorbar]

I have tried to follow [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/color-legend) example, but I get the following error:
`Module not found: Can't resolve '@d3/color-legend' in 'D:\Work\code\chart\src\components'`. Doing `npm install d3-color-legend` does not work. As I understand, the code will only work in Observable. But I would really like to use the legend in my app.

How do I fix this?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks!